MetaMask RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error while minting and listing NFTs
I am developing a fullstack Dapp to mint and list NFTs using a smart contract deployed on Ethereum. However, I keep encountering the following error when I attempt to create and list an NFT:
Create.js:110 Error minting and listing NFT: {code: -32603, message: 'Internal JSON-RPC error.'}
Here’s the relevant code snippet from my Create.js file:
import { useState } from 'react'
import { ethers } from "ethers"
import { Row, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
// import { create as ipfsHttpClient } from 'ipfs-http-client'
// const client = ipfsHttpClient('https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0')

const Create = ({ marketplace, nft }) => {
  const [fileImg, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [name, setName] = useState("")
  const [desc, setDescription] = useState("")
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("")
  // const uploadToIPFS = async (event) => {
  //   event.preventDefault()
  //   const file = event.target.files[0]
  //   if (typeof file !== 'undefined') {
  //     try {
  //       const result = await client.add(file)
  //       console.log(result)
  //       setImage(`https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${result.path}`)
  //     } catch (error){
  //       console.log("ipfs image upload error: ", error)
  //     }
  //   }
  // }

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



  const sendJSONtoIPFS = async (ImgHash) => {

    try {

      const resJSON = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinJsonToIPFS",
        data: {
          "name": name,
          "description": desc,
          "image": ImgHash
        },
        headers: {
          'pinata_api_key': process.env.REACT_APP_PINATA_API_KEY,
          'pinata_secret_api_key': process.env.REACT_APP_PINATA_SECRET_API_KEY,

        },
      });

      // https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmZ6iZAhazHyakzynC4sxZ6r6cikJmS69mZaCoyburKuq


      const tokenURI = `https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${resJSON.data.IpfsHash}`;
      console.log("Token URI", tokenURI);
      //mintNFT(tokenURI, currentAccount)   // pass the winner
      mintThenList(tokenURI)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("JSON to IPFS: ")
      console.log(error);
    }


  }


  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  const sendFileToIPFS = async (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("123");
    console.log(e);


    if (fileImg) {
      try {

        console.log("1234");
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", fileImg);
        console.log(formData)
        const resFile = await axios({
          method: "post",
          url: "https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS",
          data: formData,
          headers: {
            'pinata_api_key': process.env.REACT_APP_PINATA_API_KEY,
            'pinata_secret_api_key': process.env.REACT_APP_PINATA_SECRET_API_KEY,
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
          },
        });

        const ImgHash = `https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${resFile.data.IpfsHash}`;
        console.log(ImgHash);
        sendJSONtoIPFS(ImgHash)


      } catch (error) {
        console.log("File to IPFS: ")
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  }

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // const createNFT = async () => {
  //   if (!image || !price || !name || !description) return
  //   try{
  //     sendJSONtoIPFS(image)
  //     // const result = await client.add(JSON.stringify({image, price, name, description}))
  //     // mintThenList(result)
  //   } catch(error) {
  //     console.log("ipfs uri upload error: ", error)
  //   }
  // }
  const mintThenList = async (uri) => {
    // const uri = `https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${result.path}`
    // mint nft 
    await (await nft.mint(uri)).wait()
    // get tokenId of new nft 
    const id = await nft.tokenCount()
    // approve marketplace to spend nft
    await (await nft.setApprovalForAll(marketplace.address, true)).wait()
    // add nft to marketplace
    const listingPrice = ethers.utils.parseEther(price.toString())
    await (await marketplace.makeItem(nft.address, id, listingPrice)).wait()
  }
  return (

    <div className="container-fluid mt-5">
      <div className="row">
        <main role="main" className="col-lg-12 mx-auto" style={{ maxWidth: '1000px' }}>
          <div className="content mx-auto">
            <Row className="g-4">
              <Form.Control onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])} size="lg" required type="file" name="file" />
              <Form.Control onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} size="lg" required type="text" placeholder="Name" />
              <Form.Control onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)} size="lg" required as="textarea" placeholder="Description" />
              <Form.Control onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)} size="lg" required type="number" placeholder="Price in ETH" />
              <div className="d-grid px-0">
                <Button onClick={sendFileToIPFS} variant="primary" size="lg">
                  Create & List NFT!
                </Button>
              </div>
            </Row>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    )
}

export default Create ` 






Here is the relevant part of my smart contract:

` 
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract Marketplace is ReentrancyGuard {
    // Variables
    address payable public immutable feeAccount;  // Account that receives fees
    uint public immutable feePercent;  // Fee percentage on sales 
    uint public itemCount;  // Counter for items listed

    struct Item {
        uint itemId;  // Unique identifier for the item
        IERC721 nft;  // NFT contract address
        uint tokenId;  // Token ID of the NFT
        uint price;  // Price of the item
        address payable seller;  // Seller's address
        bool sold;  // Status of the item (sold or not)
    }

    mapping(uint => Item) public items;

    event Offered(
        uint indexed itemId,
        address indexed nft,
        uint tokenId,
        uint price,
        address seller
    );

    event Bought(
        uint indexed itemId,
        address indexed nft,
        uint tokenId,
        uint price,
        address seller,
        address buyer
    );

    constructor(uint _feePercent) {
        require(_feePercent > 0, "Fee percent must be greater than zero");
        feeAccount = payable(msg.sender);
        feePercent = _feePercent;
    }

    // Function to list an NFT for sale on the marketplace
    function makeItem(IERC721 _nft, uint _tokenId, uint _price) external nonReentrant {
        require(_price > 0, "Price must be greater than zero");
        require(_nft.ownerOf(_tokenId) == msg.sender, "Sender must own the NFT");
        require(_nft.isApprovedForAll(msg.sender, address(this)), "Marketplace not approved to transfer NFT");

        // Increment itemCount and transfer NFT to marketplace contract
        itemCount++;
        
        _nft.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _tokenId);
        
        // Add new item to items mapping
        items[itemCount] = Item({
            itemId: itemCount,
            nft: _nft,
            tokenId: _tokenId,
            price: _price,
            seller: payable(msg.sender),
            sold: false
        });

        emit Offered(itemCount, address(_nft), _tokenId, _price, msg.sender);
    }

    // Function to purchase an NFT from the marketplace
    function purchaseItem(uint _itemId) external payable nonReentrant {
        Item storage item = items[_itemId];
        
        require(_itemId > 0 && _itemId <= itemCount, "Invalid item ID");
        require(msg.value >= getTotalPrice(_itemId), "Not enough ether to cover item price and market fee");
        require(!item.sold, "Item already sold");

        // Pay seller and feeAccount using call to prevent reentrancy issues
        (bool sellerPaymentSuccess,) = item.seller.call{value: item.price}("");
        require(sellerPaymentSuccess, "Transfer to seller failed");

        (bool feePaymentSuccess,) = feeAccount.call{value: msg.value - item.price}("");
        require(feePaymentSuccess, "Transfer to fee account failed");

        // Mark the item as sold and transfer the NFT to the buyer
        item.sold = true;
        
        item.nft.transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, item.tokenId);

        emit Bought(_itemId, address(item.nft), item.tokenId, item.price, item.seller, msg.sender);
    }

    // Function to calculate total price including fees for a specific item
    function getTotalPrice(uint _itemId) view public returns (uint) {
        return (items[_itemId].price * (100 + feePercent)) / 100;
    }
}

and i keep getting this error: inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. 
{code: -32603, message: 'Internal JSON-RPC error.'} `

